# Special first item for android spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I need to make a spinner like on picture below. My question is - how to add arrow(dropdown hint) to right part for first element in spinner. Better if it(I mean arrow but not "Select test") will disappear after user press it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in spinner arraylist zero position as "Select Type" and you want to add arrow So,you need to take image view in right side of your spinner,and when you get spinner item selected position is 0 at that time you need to visible imageview and other position hide imagview.

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.